# How can I enable scroll-bar only when window is resized smaller?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

One page website.
Header at the top with anchor links
To different divs (sections) on the page.

Say my screen resolution is 1280*800 and each div section is max 800 and the content on each div section is visible when my browser is maximum size. I forgot to mention that scrolling is disabled so the other divs are only visible (scrolled automatically) using the anchor links at the top. So heres the problem, when I resize my browser, say for example theres only 450px worth of height on my browser, I can only see that amount of content on the screen and cannot scroll until the bottom of the div, so it hits the bottom of my browser.

Another point to understand is that all the elements in the div itself are not overflowing the height of the div so a simple overflow does not work because the issue is to do with the size of the browsers' height.

In essence when the browser window is anything less than 800px, the div is then covered up at the bottom by the amount reduced by the browser. I want the whole div (NOT THE CONTENT INSIDE IT) to be pushed up (top position) as far as it needs to so that the bottom of the div i.e. 800th pixel touches the bottom of the browser.

Any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen to changes in the window size and adjust the size of your divs to it. This way the div will always have the size of the window, so if it gets too small its overflow will show.

```
$("div").css("height", $(window).height());
$(​window​).bind("resize",function() {
    $("div").css("height", $(window).height());
});​​​​
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vQ2e/). Remember to set the div's overflow to `auto`, so they will show when the screen gets too small.

**Update:** from what I could understand in your update, your requirements can be satisfied with simple CSS. Let the `html, body` overflow at will, but set the "container" `div`'s overflow to `hidden` (so it will only scroll one page at a time) and its `height` to `800px`. When the browser window is resized to less than 800 px, the body's scroll bars will appear, letting you scroll the container div up and down. Both the container and the contentes will remain the same size: 800px.

```
html,body {
    overflow: auto;
}

.container, .contents {
    height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Working example at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3vQ2e/1/). Is that what you need? If you literally want to push the container div up until its bottom is aligned to the window, try setting `padding-top` or `margin-top` instead of `top` (though in this case I don't know how the scrolling will work).

Comment: your answer is along the lines of what I need, basically if the browser is less than 800px tall, then the scroll needs to move the top position of the div while they scroll until the bottom of the div hits the bottom of the browser. Any clue?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand how this is different than what my example showed. Could you explain more?

Comment: First question: I don't really have much experience writing "pure" JavaScript, I've always used web frameworks such as jQuery (which I assumed was ok since your question is tagged with it). I'm afraid someone else will have to answer it. Second question: just adapt your selector to your needs. `$("#myelement")` to select for id, `$(".myclass")` to select for class, etc.

Comment: Im not talking about pure javascript, Im asking where do I put it, as in is it just `<script>your code above</script>` or is it `<script>somethinghere | your code | something here </script `

Comment: okay heres the confusion. In the JsFiddle, the overflow only occurs when the screen overlaps the div, which is fine. because the content inside is hidden. my problem is I have a container(diV) with other divs inside. the container is 800px height, and the content does not exceed this. the whole objective is to push the top position of the actual div above the screen.

Comment: @MuhammedBhikha As Jan said, inside `$(document).ready(function() { ... })`. As for your other requirements, check my update and see if that's what you need.

Comment: Got it working more or less. Thanks guys, just one little problem. In the code above that @mgibsonbr kindly provided. Is there anyway, I can specify how many pixels are scrollable? At the moment the scroll-ability depends on the height set in the CSS, what if I want to specify the amount of scroll?

Comment: @MuhammedBhikha A **combination** of both techniques, using nested containers, might be just what you need. An "outer" `div` that changes size when the window resizes (similar to my first answer), and an "inner" `div` that stays the same size and is scrolled inside the outer `div` (similar to my second answer). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/3vQ2e/2/). (BTW you have control of the CSS, you can "specify the amount of scroll" as much as you want - statically, changing the css file, or dynamically, calling `$.css` on the desired elements)

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  body { overflow: auto; } /* Or change the height or whatever */ 
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the body has an overflow of hidden set as standard. basically my content never exceeds 800px height, so I need the scroll to be enabled anything less than 800px.

Comment: Then change 450px to 800px or whatever value you need?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution to set min-height of main wrap 800px, else you have to add overflow hidden for your main content. Scrolling can be triggered by setting main content top position, but it must be absolute or similar. You cat write a function witch helps you to move main content changing it's top position.